# Regex and powershell - Get string before slash

Tags: regex, string, powershell, replace

I have a list of directories with files like this:

```
testing_module/forms/node.js
terraform_packer/globals.js
protection_list/forms/security.js
```

I want to get with `powershell` only the folder before the slash:

```
testing_module
terraform_packer
protection_list
```

I use `-replace` with this regex expression to test it:

```
'testing_module/forms/node.js' -replace '/([^/]+/[^/]+)$'
```

But it returns the full line.

What should I use?

Comment: Are your strings literally what you presented or is there something before them like `C:/myfolder/`?

Comment: You forgot to add `, ''` at the end. `'testing_module/forms/node.js' -replace '/([^/]+/[^/]+)$', ''`

Comment: @S.Jovan That doesn't actually matter, the substitution pattern defaults to an empty string if left unspecified

Comment: Your use case is ambiguous. You say you want only the folder before the file but your last example states it should output the name of the folder two folders above the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace the first `/` and everything after with:

```
'testing_module/forms/node.js' -replace '\/.*$'
```

or use `-split` and grab only the first resulting part:

```
@('testing_module/forms/node.js' -split '/')[0]
# or 
'testing_module/forms/node.js' -split '/' |Select -First 1
```

or use the `String.Remove()` and `String.IndexOf()` methods:

```
$str = 'testing_module/forms/node.js'
$str.Remove($str.IndexOf('/'))
```

Comment: The first solution returns what I wanted !

Answer (score 2):

I see that as matching rather than replacing. Match any character that's not a forward slash until you meet a forward slash:

```
'testing_module/forms/node.js' -match '[^/]+'
$matches[0]
'terraform_packer/globals.js' -match '[^/]+'  
$matches[0]
'protection_list/forms/security.js' -match '[^/]+'
$matches[0]
```

It works with folders of any depth.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's nicer to positively search for what you are looking for rather than to remove what you are not looking for. Here we search from the beginning of the string for the biggest substring that doesn't contain a slash.

```
PS> "testing_module/forms/node.js" -match "^[^/]*"
True
PS> $matches[0]
testing_module
```